# Pydantic - how to skip validation of other fields if one of the fields fails?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Let's say I have a simple `pydantic.BaseModel` like this:

```py
from myapp import User
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class ChangePasswordRequest(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True  # because I'm using my `User` arbitrary type

    user: User
    current_password: constr(min_length=1, max_length=255)
    new_password: constr(min_length=8, max_length=64)
    
    @validator("user")
    def user_is_active(cls, user: User):
        assert not user.inactive, "User is not active."
        return user

    @validator("current_password")
    def current_password_validator(cls, password: str, values: Dict[str, Any]):
        user: User = values["user"]
        assert user.check_password(password), "current_password is not valid."
        return password
```

This is the model I'd like to use to handle user's password change. When I create `ChangePasswordRequest` with `inactive` user, I get a `KeyError`, because `pydatinc` validates all the fields.

```py
from myapp import User

user = User(inactive=True)
r = ChangePasswordRequest(user=user, current_password="current", new_password="new-password")

# I get
KeyError: 'user'
```

The reason why it happens:

- `user_is_active` is called and validation fails. `values["user"]` is not set as an effect
- `current_password_validator` is called. `values["user"]` key does not exist and `KeyError` is raised.

What I want to achieve is to skip all validation if `user` field validation fails as there is no point of further validation. This is not a problem for a small model like mine as I can add an `if` statement in each validator, but this gets annoying as model grows.

```py
@validator("current_password")
def current_password_validator(cls, password: str, values: Dict[str, Any]):
    if not user := values.get("user"):
        return password
    assert user.check_password(password), "current_password is not valid."
    return password
```

Other way would be to use `root_validator(pre=True)`, but there is another problem with this approach. Error is located in the `__root__` field, instead of `user` field.

```py
@root_validator(pre=True)
def user_is_active(cls, values: Dict[str, Any]):
    user: Union[User, None] = values.get("user", None)
    assert getattr(user, "is_active", False), "User is not active."
    return values

# which produces following error:
[{'loc': ['__root__'],
  'msg': 'User is not active.',
  'type': 'assertion_error'}]
```

Does `pydantic` have any feature that will stop further validation if one of the "main" or "crucial" fields fails?

Comment: `assert` is only evaluated when python runs in debug mode. Since you explicitly want to abort validation, raise a ValueError instead?

Comment: This is not the case with debug mode. Raising `ValueError` does not stop validation of succeeding fields either.

Comment: Hi @umat did you find a good solution? Running into a similar issue, I wish there was a `skip_on_failure` option for regular `@pydantic.validator`..

Comment: Hello @twhughes, unfortunately - not much changed, I just had to go with additional "if" statements to skip validation.

Comment: @umat thanks for the update. I ended up just using a similar solution where I defined a `get_value(key:str, values:dict) -> Any` function that tries to run `values.get(key)` and raises a `ValidationError` if the result is `None`. Then I just used this in my code instead of `values[key]` or `values.get(key)` (if `None` is not an allowed value) and it's been working out ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to stop execution after the first validator, you can begin the second one with something like this:

```
if "user" not in values:
    raise ValueError("Could not validate current_password because user did not pass validation")
```